# error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Tags: php, apache, pear, pecl

I'm trying to make some HTTP request with Apache but it gives me an error saying

> fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Why do I need to handle HTTP requests with an HTTP extension (pecl/pear)? Why does not running a web serve handle it?

Comment: The `HttpRequest` class provides functions/methods for PHP to make HTTP requests.

Comment: Doing HTTP requests has nothing to do with running a webserver.

Comment: my point is i have apache , why doesnt apache handles the http request im making, why does it require tht i use pecl /pear extension

Comment: Because a web server isn't a client.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, how is this related to PEAR, PECL, or Apache?